# Terminating python script through emacs

Tags: python, emacs, terminate

I am running a python interpreter through emacs. I often find myself running python scripts and wishing I could terminate them without killing the entire buffer. That is because I do not want to import libraries all over again...

Is there a way to tell python to stop executing a script and give me a prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using keyboard interrupt which `comint` send to the interpreter through <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>.

I generally hold down the <kbd>C-c</kbd> until it the prompt returns.